# Sharepoint file sharing - external contact autofill

Tags: sharepoint-online, share, external-users, auto-populate

I have question about how to share files with external users.

I wish that my contacts(external) will be auto-filled while typing the email/name.

Below example with internal users:

[image]

So overall: you're sharing a file, and starting to type the username/email.

SharePoint prompts the suggested name. That's obvious.

BUT I wish to use my contacts (external contacts) to be prompted with same behavior. I know that it'll work with Azure Guest Account. But is there any other way to update the auto-fill list?

All ready checked the Contacts app.

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no method to configure the auto-fill for external users.

You may need to develop custom SPFx by yourself to achieve this requirement.

A series of articles about SPFx:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview